# How do I complete the statue puzzle?

Tags: republique

I have entered the room outside of the Headmaster's office and there are seven statues arranged in the entrance:

[image]

How do I complete the statue puzzle and open the entrance to the Headmaster's office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate each statue in order of the dates on the plaques.

[image]

The statues are of the following people:

- Plato  428 BC - 347 BC
- Charlemagne  748 - 815
- Yataro Iwasaki  1835 - 1885
- Theodore Vail  1845 - 1920
- Vladimir Lenin  1870 - 1924
- Eva Peron  1919 - 1952
- Treglazov  1945 - ?

The statues will light up when activated in the correct order. Plato is already active, so starting from Charlemagne the statues need activating in the following order:

[image]